# Wildfly failed to start ISPN000280: Caught exception [java.lang.StackOverflowError]

Tags: infinispan, wildfly-9

Getting following exception for our application with wildfly 9.0.1 running in cluster environment, after which wildfly became unresponsive. 
It looks similar to bug:[WFLY-5697] ISPN000136: Execution error: CacheListenerException: ISPN000280: Caught exception StackOverflowError while i…, which I think has been fixed with wildfly 10. Do you know what could have triggered this ? Is ther any workaround that we can put in wildfly 9.0.1

Exception:

```
12-Jul-2016 21:59:26,809 ERROR [InvocationContextInterceptor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.commons.CacheListenerException: ISPN000280: Caught exception [java.lang.StackOverflowError] while invoking method [public void org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.removed(org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryRemovedEvent)] on listener instance: org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager@2e3b0daa
at org.infinispan.notifications.impl.AbstractListenerImpl$ListenerInvocationImpl$1.run(AbstractListenerImpl.java:291) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.WithinThreadExecutor.execute(WithinThreadExecutor.java:22) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.notifications.impl.AbstractListenerImpl$ListenerInvocationImpl.invoke(AbstractListenerImpl.java:309) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.CacheNotifierImpl$BaseCacheEntryListenerInvocation.doRealInvocation(CacheNotifierImpl.java:1212) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.CacheNotifierImpl$BaseCacheEntryListenerInvocation.invokeNoChecks(CacheNotifierImpl.java:1207) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.CacheNotifierImpl$BaseCacheEntryListenerInvocation.invoke(CacheNotifierImpl.java:1184) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.CacheNotifierImpl.notifyCacheEntryRemoved(CacheNotifierImpl.java:356) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.notify(RemoveCommand.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.performRemove(RemoveCommand.java:208) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.perform(RemoveCommand.java:93) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor.handleDefault(CallInterceptor.java:124) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:49) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TxDistributionInterceptor.handleTxWriteCommand(TxDistributionInterceptor.java:306) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TxDistributionInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(TxDistributionInterceptor.java:86) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor.invokeNextAndApplyChanges(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:388) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor.setSkipRemoteGetsAndInvokeNextForDataCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:453) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:252) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:147) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:65) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:111) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:49) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistWriteAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:367) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(TxInterceptor.java:273) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:111) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:49) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:58) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97) [infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar:7.2.3.Final]
```

Comment: WFLY-5697 won't be fixed, so I suggest upgrading to a newer WildFly.